# Add class to parent div when radio button is checked and remove class if other radio is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was able add a class to the parent div when the radio button is checked.
Now when i want to click on the other radio button I want to remove the class on the previous div.

This is what i have :

```js
$(".radio").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass('selected-prize');
  }
});
```

```css
.selected-prize {
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prize-wrapper">
  <div class="prize">
    <h1>Cooking class <br> Cooking class</h1>
    <div class="img-holder">
      <img src="{{ asset('assets/images/emo.png') }}" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="radio" type="radio" id="test3" name="radio-group2">
      <label for="test3">Select</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="prize-wrapper">
  <div class="prize">
    <h1>Cooking class <br> Cooking class</h1>
    <div class="img-holder">
      <img src="{{ asset('assets/images/emo.png') }}" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="radio" type="radio" id="test4" name="radio-group2">
      <label for="test4">Select</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add `$('.prize-wrapper').removeClass('selected-prize')` before your `if`

Comment: Instead of multiple `parent()` calls use `.closest('.prize-wrapper')`; this will also prevent the code from breaking if you change the structure too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first remove class `selected-prize`:

```js
$(".radio").change(function() {
  $(".prize-wrapper").removeClass('selected-prize');

  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass('selected-prize');
  }
});
```

```css
.selected-prize {
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prize-wrapper">
  <div class="prize">
    <h1>Cooking class <br /> Cooking class</h1>
    <div class="img-holder">
      <img src="{{ asset('assets/images/emo.png') }}" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="radio" type="radio" id="test3" name="radio-group2" />
      <label for="test3">Select</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="prize-wrapper">
  <div class="prize">
    <h1>Cooking class <br /> Cooking class</h1>
    <div class="img-holder">
      <img src="{{ asset('assets/images/emo.png') }}" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="radio" type="radio" id="test4" name="radio-group2" />
      <label for="test4">Select</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".radio").change(function() {
  $('.prize-wrapper').removeClass('selected-prize');
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).closest('.selected-prize').addClass('selected-prize');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".radio").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('.selected-prize').each(function(){
      $(this).removeClass('selected-prize');
    });
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass('selected-prize');
  }
});
```

```css
.selected-prize {
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prize-wrapper">
  <div class="prize">
    <h1>Cooking class <br> Cooking class</h1>
    <div class="img-holder">
      <img src="{{ asset('assets/images/emo.png') }}" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="radio" type="radio" id="test3" name="radio-group2">
      <label for="test3">Select</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="prize-wrapper">
  <div class="prize">
    <h1>Cooking class <br> Cooking class</h1>
    <div class="img-holder">
      <img src="{{ asset('assets/images/emo.png') }}" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="radio" type="radio" id="test4" name="radio-group2">
      <label for="test4">Select</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".radio").change(function() {
  var prize = $(this).parent().parent().parent()
  prize.toggleClass('selected-prize').siblings().removeClass('selected-prize');
});
```